# Control, find and connect wifi hotspots using iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, find, wifi

How can I control the Wifi hardware on my iPhone from within an application such as WifiTrak is doing it? Is that app using private APIs maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WifiTrak and similar apps used private APIs, and therefore they have recently been removed from the App Store.

Currently, using private APIs is the only way to accomplish this, but your app will almost certainly be rejected if you do so.